# Determine the "left" and "right" side of a split shapely geometry

Tags: python, shapely

My question is: how can I determine which of the `Aside` and `Bside` sides of [an already split rotated rectangular geometry](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/dl.dropbox.com/s/ll3mchnx0jwzjnf/determine%20left-right%20split.ipynb) are the "left" and "right" side of an arbitrary `LineString` that splits that geometry?

For the purposes of this problem, "left" and "right" are defined as the left-hand and right-hand side of a `LineString` splitter when "walking" from node to node, in order.

I've created this function for splitting *any* arbitrary `shapely` geometry (non collection) into two sides - the "left" and the "right":

```
import shapely.geometry as geo
import shapely.ops as ops

def splitLR(geom, splitter):
    """Split a geometry into a 'left' and 'right' side using the shapely API"""
    if not isinstance(splitter, geo.LineString):
        raise TypeError("The splitter must be a LineString")
    if not splitter.is_simple:
        raise ValueError("Only simple splitter objects allowed")
    if hasattr(geom, "__iter__"):
        raise ValueError("Geometry collections not allowed")
    geom_extents = geo.GeometryCollection([geom, splitter]).minimum_rotated_rectangle
    sides = ops.split(geom_extents, splitter)
    try:
        Aside, Bside = sides
    except TypeError:
        # only 1 result - rotated rectangle wasn't split
        if len(ops.split(geom,splitter)) == 1:
            # geom isn't split by splitter
            raise ValueError("the splitter does not appear to split the geometry")
        else:
            # splitter too small for algorithm
            raise ValueError("the splitter must extend beyond minimum_rotated_rectangle "
                             "of the combined geometry")
    # determine which is Lside and Rside here
    Lside,Rside = get_LRsides(Aside, Bside, splitter)
    return tuple(side.intersection(geom) for side in (Lside, Rside))
```

The idea of the above is illustrated in the notebook linked here (same link as above):

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/dl.dropbox.com/s/ll3mchnx0jwzjnf/determine%20left-right%20split.ipynb

To summarize: sides A and B are the two sides of the [`minimum_rotated_rectangle`](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#constructive-methods) surrounding the `geom` geometry and the `splitter` line string together. When `side.intersection(geom)` is executed, the result is the portion of the originally given geometry `geom` contained in that side.

Notes:

- it is possible- for oddly shaped "potato" type objects- for this intersection to result in multiple objects on one or both sides (see the nbviewer example)
- I have created my own function here (rather than using `ops.split`) because the `ops.split` function just returns a "bag" of split objects, and there isn't a way to determine which side they are on (that I'm aware of)

Currently my call to `get_LRsides` just executes this function, which is obviously worthless:

```
def get_LRsides(Aside, Bside, splitter):
    """Determine the 'left' and 'right' sides of an already split geometry"""
    return Aside,Bside
```

How can I successfully label A and B as "left" and "right"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could work:

1. Form a `LinearRing` with the end-points of the splitter and a point in Aside
2. Apply `object.is_ccw`
3. If it returns `True`, Aside is to the left of the splitter.

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.is_ccw

Answer (score 0):

I am not the sharpest GIS tool in the toolbox and was struggling to figure out how to "add a point in Aside" to the LinearRing in the accepted answer.  Here's the hack I can up with in its place.

I project two points of the intersecting splitter LineString onto the exterior of the first polygon, which provides me a distance along that exterior linestring.  If that distance is increasing, then the first polygon is the "right" side of the splitting.

Here's an example code:

```py
from shapely.ops import split
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString, Point


def rhs_split(poly, splitter):
    intersect_splitter = splitter.intersection(poly)
    geomcollect = split(poly, splitter)
    polya, polyb = geomcollect.geoms[0], geomcollect.geoms[1]
    # Test directionality
    pt0 = Point(intersect_splitter.coords[0])
    pt1 = Point(intersect_splitter.coords[1])
    start_dist = polya.exterior.project(pt0)
    end_dist = polya.exterior.project(pt1)
    return polya if end_dist > start_dist else polyb


print(
    rhs_split(
        Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)]),
        LineString([(0.5, -0.1), (0.5, 1.1)]),
    )
)
# POLYGON ((0.5 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0.5 0, 0.5 1))
print(
    rhs_split(
        Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)]),
        LineString([(0.5, 1.1), (0.5, -0.1)]),
    )
)
# POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 0.5 1, 0.5 0, 0 0))
```