# Group Polygons after splitting MultiPolygon with LineString

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I wish to split a MultiPolygon (representing a country with islands) via a LineString, thereby splitting the county in two.

```
from shapely.ops import split
collection_of_polyogns = split(country,line)
```

This results is a set of Polygons in a GeometryCollection object. How would you group the result into two MultiPolygon objects, with each containing the Polygons for their respective half?

**UPDATE**

The question:
[Determine the "left" and "right" side of a split shapely geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393718/determine-the-left-and-right-side-of-a-split-shapely-geometry) offers a good solution where a point is taken from each Polygon in the result to see if it forms a clockwise or anti-clockwise Linestring when combined with the splitting LineString. But am thinking of using the centroid for each polygon instead since it is guaranteed to not be on the splitting line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine the "left" and "right" side of a split shapely geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393718/determine-the-left-and-right-side-of-a-split-shapely-geometry)

Comment: @Georgy I think so. I will test it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So first you have your countries MultiPolygon, and then your split polygons:

```
from shapely.ops import split
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPolygon
#Somewhere you get your country and your line vars
collection_of_polygons = split(country,line)
```

Then you make a polygon of the original boundary of your countries MutliPolygon, and perform the same split with the line:

```
bounds = country.bounds
p1 = Point(bounds[0],bounds[-1])
p2 = Point(bounds[0],bounds[1])
p3 = Point(bounds[-2],bounds[1])
p4 = Point(bounds[-2],bounds[-1])

point_list = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p1]
bounds_poly = Polygon(point_list)

boundaries = shapely.ops.split(bounds_poly,line)
```

Make two lists, and iterate over the split country polygons to check if they are within the first polygon from the boundaries split polygon:

```
group1, group2 = [],[]
for x in collection_of_polygons:
    if x.within(boundaries[0]):
        group1.append(x)
    else:
        group2.append(x)
```

Finally assign the two lists two two different MultiPolygons:

```
group_multi1 = MultiPolygon(group1)
group_multi2 = MultiPolygon(group2)
```

Comment: I have only one country. Its in a MultiPolygon because it has some islands.

Comment: Can you please clarify as to why having only one country is a problem in this context?